# Icon Zoom missing in Plank

Tags: 20.04, plank

I am using plank on my Ubuntu 20.04. Yesterday, I updated my packages using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After that, the plank feature "icon zoom" is missing in plank preferences.
I am using plank version 0.11.89 got from `plank --version`

The plank preferences screenshot is:

[image: Plank preference Image]

Is the feature removed? How can i get it back?

Comment: The feature still exists. Probably it's not displayed due to bold fonts or desktop theme.

Comment: I have changed the theme and fonts and the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the same question in launchpad ppa of plank and got the answer from the author itself.
Here is the link to that:
[Launchpad Question Link](https://answers.launchpad.net/plank/+question/691904)